# Не получается посчитать сумму цифр всех чисел в списке

Tags: python

Написать рекурсивную функцию подсчета суммы элементов списка чисел.

```
def summ_l(x, n = 0):
    if n >= len(x):
        return 0
    lz = x[n] % 10
    chick = lz
    lx = x[n] // 10
    if lx == 0:
        return 0
    if lx != 0:
        return chick + summ_l(lx)
    else:
        return chick + summ_l(x, n+1)

print(summ_l([42, 24, 15, 18]))
```

Comment: Нет, в том вопросе сумма чисел, а тут сумма цифр всех чисел

Comment: Решение подойдёт прекрасно

Comment: Я же сказал сумма всех цифр в списке...

Comment: Он считает сумму всех цифр в списке (99 т.к 42 + 24 + 15 + 18 = 99)

Comment: Он считает числа, а я говорю про цифры, должно быть 4+2+2+4+1+5+1+8 = 27

Comment: Исправлено, проверяйте ниже :)

Comment: Отформатируйте код в своем вопросе.

Comment: Отформатировал!

Answer (score 3):

Вот решение:

```
def summ_l(n):
    if not n:
        return 0
    return sum([int(i) for i in list(str(n[0]))]) + summ_l(n[1:])

print(summ_l([42, 24, 15, 18]))
```